# ASP MVC 5 OAuth External Login and SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

Is it a must to use **SSL** in order to use OAuth login on ASP MVC5? as suggested in this post?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for an answer to the same question, and found a very good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862847/819464

Bottom line is that while it may not be a technical requirement, you don't have a secure solution if you don't. There is not compelling reason not to use SSL for OAuth in MVC.