# OAuth /token 404 [not found] in IIS. But working in local.

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, iis-7.5

I am working on Angular with WebAPI in same solution. when I call OAuth token method it is working fine in Local. But, not working in IIS. below is the code.

```
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {


       IKernel kernel = IocConfig.GetKernel;
        IocConfig.RegisterIoc(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        var AuthProvider = kernel.Get<DigitalSignageAuthorizationProvider>();
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3),
            Provider = AuthProvider,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        });
        //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        var oauthConfig = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = "Bearer"

        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(oauthConfig);

    }
```

Angular Code

```
 function userLoginToken(data) {
        var self = this;
        console.log(data);
        return self.postData('/token', data);
    }
```

post data has $resource api call.

Comment: Please put the working url and not working url

Comment: working url : localhost:9115/token  ||  Not working url : ct.companyname.com/token

Comment: Did you hosted your application on IIS with .net framework registered? Is your Virtual directory pointing to the same folder structure

Comment: Yes hosted. login page come correctly. when click login button, it tells that [website]/token not found.

Comment: Is your application directly hosted with domain name like ct.companyname.com/ or ct.companyname.com/Yourapplication? Can you please share the login url that is accessible from IIS

Comment: Are you using https ? I think OAUTH API doesn't work to non-secured domains. It still work in local though because it's not considered as non secure (hopefully). I may misunderstood your problem, but you should read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860693/are-oauth2-client-apps-required-to-have-ssl-connection

Comment: It is already working fine[before 10 day]. Now only not working,  for insecure we have given  AllowInsecureHttp = true