# login with google oauth2 and using API to get contacts

Tags: google-oauth

I am starting to develop a web service and I want to enable login with google using their oAuth2. However, when I started reading the requirements I see that I need to authorize my domain and use https. I am in the very initial steps and I still don't have the domain setup and no certificate yet.

Is there any way to test google integrated into my site without all this? only for development phase?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Oauth2 client apps required to have SSL connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860693/are-oauth2-client-apps-required-to-have-ssl-connection)

Comment: No; OAuth2 explicitly requires SSL. It would be a huge security vulnerability if it didn't.

Comment: Thank you @ObsidianAge but what about the domain verification? can't I use just localhost?

Comment: as an example the `microsoft graph` api lets you skip SSL if using `localhost`. The particular service you are connecting to may also have its own exception