# OAuth2 security in REST GET API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I understand that OAuth2 is a good way to secure access to a REST API. I also understand that unlike in a simple website or in a SOAP API, in a REST API you want to use the right HTTP method for the right task. That is GET to read data, POST to write, etc.

My question is, when doing a GET call to a REST API secured via OAuth2, how do you protect your access token ? I don't see any other way to pass it to the server than in clear view in the URL, so isn't it that anybody that can see my call on the network could hijack my authorization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A HTTP request has a couple of major components:

1. The method
2. The url
3. Headers
4. Body

The OAuth2 Bearer token is usually sent in the headers, as such:

```
GET /thingy HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.org
Authorization: Bearer [secret]
```

As an aside, this assumption is not really correct either:

> so isn't it that anybody that can see my call on the network could hijack my authorization ?

If you don't use HTTPS, anyone can still see this token even if it's in a header. If you *do* use HTTPS, putting a token in the url shouldn't allow anyone else to snoop. However, putting secrets in urls is considered a bad practice for different reasons. Specifically, people don't like it because the tokens can end up in a browsers history and in logs. This increases the chances of it accidentally falling in the wrong hands.

Comment: HTTPS is mandatory for OAuth2. You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860693/are-oauth2-client-apps-required-to-have-ssl-connection